# Does Mootools prevents javascript closure 100%?

Tags: mootools, closures

While I was talking about javascript closure to my friend, I was told that using Mootools can prevent closures 100%. To my knowledege, a variable causes a closure. How does Mootools itself prevents javascript closure? I think my friend is saying that Mootools' functions are closure-safe functions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ask your friend to explain himself? Maybe you were talking about different things?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin // I think he has an idea that javascript == mootools since he started javascript with Mootools. That is why he is saying that using Mootools itself can prevent 100% javascript closures because Mootools itself indeed does not make closures.

Comment: @terrani - It doesn't prevent them...they're very useful things, in fact most frameworks have specific contextual closure creation methods, even Mootools: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Function#Function:pass

Comment: mootools DOES use closures a fair bit in its codebase. furthermore, coding for mootools more often makes you use closures than not, be it writing a class with all functions as methods or sticking all your code within the domready anonymous function. it certainly cannot PREVENT them... i `suggest` you read up on closures first...

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff // I was not the one who was saying that Mootools prevent closures. I clearly wrote "my friend".

Comment: Still, where is the question? My point was that if you'd read about closures, you'd have been be able to tell your friend that no framework can PREVENT them. You can PUNCTURE closures though, read here: http://appden.com/javascript/puncture-closures/

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff // I got your point. Thank you your link. It helped.

Answer (score 2):

A variable does not cause a closure.  A closure is created by a function A that returns another function B referring to one of A's local variables.  For example, the expression

```
  (function() {
    var x;
    return {
        get: function () { return x; },
        set: function (y) { return x=y; }
      };
  })();
```

returns an object containing two functions referring to the local variable `x`.  We say that `get` and `set` "close over" `x`.